# Smooth scrolling with CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

My question is that in web page we should apply smooth scrolling with CSS or Javascript.
I know how to do it with both , i just want to know that Which would be a better option ?

Answer (score 0):

Use css:

> scroll-behavior: smooth;

Comment: Actually i know how to do it, i wanted to know which is more preferrable ?

Answer (score -1):

Use scroll-behavior property in the html element to enable smooth scrolling for the whole page.

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Using JavaScript read [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20140213105950/http://itnewb.com/tutorial/Creating-the-Smooth-Scroll-Effect-with-JavaScript).

Comment: Actually i know how to do it, i wanted to know which is more preferrable ?